Parsing and Generating canconical versions using `python-semantic-release`
I'm using python-semantic-release to generate build versions, and poetry to manage dependencies.
My pyproject.yaml is configures as follows:
[tool.semantic_release]
upload_to_pypi = false
upload_to_vcs_release = false
build_command = "poetry build && poetry publish -r private"
tag_format = "v{version}"
version_toml = [
    "pyproject.toml:tool.poetry.version"
]
version_variables = [
    "src/***/_version.py:__version__",
]

[tool.semantic_release.branches.main]
match = "(main|master)"
prerelease_token = "rc"
prerelease = false

[tool.semantic_release.branches.other]
match = "^(feat|fix|perf)/.+"
prerelease_token = "dev"
prerelease = true

I invoke my build using semantic-release version --no-vcs-release
The issue is poetry build canonicalizes the version, i.e. if the version in pyproject.toml is 0.8.0-dev.2 then poetry (using the vendored packaging package) canonicalizes the version to 0.8.0.dev2
+ poetry build
Building my-project (0.8.0-dev.2)
  - Building sdist
  - Built my-project-0.8.0.dev2.tar.gz
  - Building wheel
  - Built my-project-0.8.0.dev2-py3-none-any.whl

The latter conforms with https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#public-version-identifiers
The canonical public version identifiers MUST comply with the following scheme:
[N!]N(.N)*[{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN]

The former doesn't. I also see errors due because semantic-release fails to parse tags that are valid but don't match the specific pattern it's looking for
"Couldn't parse tag v0.4.0.dev2 as as Version: '0.4.0.dev2' is not a valid Version"
What I'd like to do is configure semantic-release so it correctly parses canonical tags, and emits canonicalized versions into __version__.py and pyproject.yaml
Is this possible - for now I've written a script to modify the version, but it would be tidier if I could ensure both tools were consistent.
